# Processing cost of hiding vs destroying HTML DOM Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Thinking from the perspective of a SPA that has a lot of loading/unloading of different modules. For example:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="user-landing" style="display:none">
        <h2 class="title">User Page</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="container" id="home-feed">
        <h2 class="title">Feed</h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hiding and showing like `$('#user-landing').show()` works fine, but the larger the app becomes, the more attention needs to be paid to not reusing `.classes` or `#ids` that already exist in other modules - risking undesired behavior.

Destroying or unsetting the DOM elements would prevent undesired targeting of DOM elements, but at what cost?

Comment: If you have class or ID conflicts, it will be a problem either way.

Comment: I think he means, for example, if you have a SPA with multiple "pages", and each page contains a "#header" element. They don't really conflict because they don't show at the same time, but if you are just hiding elements, they would.

Comment: for performance questions: measure. then check whether you're measuring the right thing. then measure some more. often it depends a lot on the precise workload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your better option is somewhere in between, which a lot of other frameworks do. Remove it from the DOM, but don't destroy it.

To do that, you would just get a reference to it, then remove it. You'd still have it in a variable (so it isn't destroyed), but it also isn't part of the DOM so it doesn't bump into other classes and ids.

```
const someElement = document.querySelector('some-selector');
someElement.parentNode.removeChild(someElement); // remove
```

Most frameworks have some kind of cache they manage to keep track of all of these. When they shouldn't be rendered, they just aren't rendered, but they are still in the cache for quick adding back.

As for performance, except in extreme cases where RAM starts becoming a huge concern, keeping it cached and detached will always be better than destroying and recreating.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at react to evaluate this cost. From what I understand when you switch pages in a single page web app that uses react, it will destroy, or at least remove from the dom, all the dom elements that are not used in the new page.